# Mass of a gas sample

Tags: history-of-chemistry, mole

What method did John Dalton use to measure the mass of one mole of gases, for example, chlorine and hydrogen, to get their relative masses?

Answer (score 2):

The concept of a [mole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_%28unit%29#History)(c. 1805), and [Avogadro's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro%27s_number#History)(1811) occurred after Dalton formulated his [law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton%27s_law) (1801). So he would not have set out to measure a "mole of gas" as the modern formulation sets out. This history of Dalton may be useful to you: [Google Book Search](http://books.google.com/books?id=fIo-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=On%20the%20Absorption%20of%20Gases%20by%20Water%20and%20Other%20Liquids,%20John%20Dalton&source=bl&ots=8RTWb6v64Z&sig=VvRZBfCa0txIFgyKoOgKkoAOB9c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=j-h3UqqqGqnXygHbioCgAw&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=On%20the%20Absorption%20of%20Gases%20by%20Water%20and%20Other%20Liquids,%20John%20Dalton&f=false) Most of his work centered around pressure readings, as his early interests were meterological.

Comment: thanks for you answer,the reason I am asking this question is that i want to know how the relative atomic mass of the elements were obtained during that time.
I know that at room temperature and pressure sample of gases of any element with same volume contain the same amount of atoms and we can use it to know the relative masses of the elements compared to hydrogen. 
But how did he obtain the mass of the gas sample?

Answer (score 0):

To set '*relative*' weights, Dalton took the lightest element known, hydrogen, and set an atomic weight of 1. Then he started to weigh other compounds,e.g., water and determined the ratios of the other elements. From this data, Dalton set the relative weight of several elements.